# Jquery only showing on click - not on load and click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been trying to get my divs to display per click - which works..... However, I want Div1 to be shown - but Div2 and Div3 hidden until clicked and when clicked, the current visible div should be hidden.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#tabs li a").click(function(){
        $(".platform").hide();
        var myDiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(myDiv).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.platform {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1">PC</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">PS4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">XBOX</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="platform tab1" id="tab1">
  <div> 
    platform 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab2" id="tab2">
  <div> 
    platform 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab3" id="tab3">
  <div> 
    platform 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I've managed to get the following:
Show all on load and show none until a click is registered. But onlick seems to not work when I add in the classes:

```
Show (display:block;)
hide (display:none;)
```

What could be causing this?

I would like for tab1 to show on page load, but tab 2 and tab 3 only show when clicked..... But that also hides the current active div.

Is there another method to onclick?

Comment: Can you please show the full code? For instance, your javascript references a `#tabs` id but I do not see that in your HTML

Comment: I've edited the comment @Pytth - tabs is the clickable list - sorry trying to reveal too much of the project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the first tab in your css. JQuery will add it's own CSS which will have a higher specificity on click.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#tabs li a").click(function(){
        $(".platform").hide();
        var myDiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(myDiv).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.platform {
    display: none;
}
.platform.tab1 { /* <-- I added this */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1">PC</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">PS4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">XBOX</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="platform tab1" id="tab1">
  <div> 
    platform 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab2" id="tab2">
  <div> 
    platform 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab3" id="tab3">
  <div> 
    platform 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Dom - firstly nice to e-meet you. Thanks for editing the question. I'll give this a whirl - it's strange as normally I use onlick but it appears to not work anymore.

Comment: You nailed it - is that really where I went wrong? Damn. 

I usually onclick to add/remove classes to divs, but I think this was causing issues. Thanks so much - you provided the info to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.hide()` and `.show()` you could use a `show` class. Include this in the class of the first tab, then change it in the click handler.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs li a").click(function() {
    $(".platform.show").removeClass("show");
    var myDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(myDiv).addClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.platform {
  display: none;
}

.platform.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1">PC</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">PS4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">XBOX</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="platform tab1 show" id="tab1">
  <div>
    platform 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab2" id="tab2">
  <div>
    platform 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="platform tab3" id="tab3">
  <div>
    platform 3
  </div>
</div>
```